# How to insert multiple results from a query into another table?

Tags: php, mysql

my query is below :

```
$qStuff=mysql_query("SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name,t.category_code, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_id = t.category_id AND t.domain_id = d.domain_id AND c.field_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($first_word) . "'");
```

From the query above,the query will return the result where the input match the field_name in the table.

eg

Field_name : Define
(Result from the `$qStuff` query)
(Field_name>Category>Domain)
Define>P1>Cognitive
Define>C1>Affective

I have to store them in a table so that i know from that table the define has P1 and C1 as category and Cognitive and Affective as domain.How should i do that ?What will the insert query looks like ? Please help ,thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So you got some result and you want to insert it into database table. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html. They have everything you are looking for.

Comment: @zerkms: I got that links from Google, went there and saw what they have. Really, I don't care what's website name, but still GOT YOUR POINT :) Actually, I prefer official documentation.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: w3fools.com describes why you shouldn't refer there ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: I've read that already but to be honest, did not think about it before posting w3s link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to perform separated `SELECT` query, because of there is a special construct in mysql for such cases: [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)